# <li class="active"><a href="index.html"></a></li> not working for me, color of an icon is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem linking html(`<li class="active"><a href="index.html"></a></li>`) to icons and I do not know how to make icons different color after I click on them (color of an icon is black, when I click on an icon it does not stay white). I tried another way to get html in but then the animation did not work. I looked at millions of pages and I could not find an answer. On top of that, I am new to coding.

```css
body
{

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: #273847;

}
ul
{
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
min-width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 0;
background: #2b3e4f;
display: flex;
border-radius: 10px;

}
ul li
{

list-style: none;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
ul li:last-child
{

border-right: none;

}
ul li a
{

text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 27px;
display: block;

}
ul li a .icon
{

width: 40px;
height: 90px;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto 10px;

}
ul li a .icon .fa
{

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 40px;
transition: 0.5s;
color: #0a0e12;
}

ul li a .icon .fa:last-child
{

color: #eeeeee;

}
ul li a:hover .icon .fa
{

transform: translateY(-100%);

}

/*
ul li a .name
{

position: relative;
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;

}

ul li a .name span
{

display: block;
position: relative;
color: #000;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
transition: 0.5s;

}

ul li a .name span:before
{

content: attr(data-text);
position: absolute;
top: -100%;
left 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #eeeeee;

}

ul li a:hover .name span
{

transform: translateY(20px);

}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>

  <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <ul>

    <div>

      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

      <li>
        <a>
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="icon"><span data-text="Home">Home</span></div> -->
        </a>
      </li>

      <div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html"></a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="icon"><span data-text="About">About</span></div> -->
        </a>
      </li>

      <div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="icon"><span data-text="Contact">Contact</span></div> -->
        </a>
      </li>

      <div>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="settings.html"></a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <li>
        <a>
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="icon"><span data-text="Settings">Settings</span></div> -->
        </a>
      </li>


    </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: This may help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095907/how-to-change-color-when-click-icon-in-css

Comment: Did you mean show active icons based on the url, like if the url is like www.demo.com/contact, then the mail icon should get active color ( white )

Comment: @rootkonda i tried this, but it seems it doesnt help me, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hyperlys Please resolve your problem first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you can solve this issue with a css-only solution - I might be wrong though.

Nevertheless you can do it with some Javascript trickery which goes a little like this:

- layer an additional icon on top of your current icons, give it the desired color e.g. red and make it invisible by setting it's css opacity property to 0
- attach a click event listener to the freshly created icons
- inside the callback handler reset the opacity of all the red active icons to 0, reset the opacity of all the icons below (those that are used for the CSS animation effect) to 1, make the clicked icon visible and finally the two icons in the background invisible.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
buttons[0].addEventListener("click", clicked);

function clicked(e) {
  var iconsToShow = document.querySelectorAll(`[class*="icon"]`);
  iconsToShow.forEach(
    function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
      currentValue.style.opacity = 1;
    });

  var iconsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(`[class*="active"]`);
  iconsToHide.forEach(
    function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
      currentValue.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0;
    });

  var iconToHide = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`[class*="icon"]`)[0];

  iconToHide.style.opacity = 0;
  e.target.style.opacity = 1;
}

for (var a = 0; a < buttons.length; a++) {
  buttons[a].addEventListener("click", clicked);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #273847;
}

ul {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #2b3e4f;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 27px;
  display: block;
}

ul li a .icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
}

ul li a .icon .fa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #0a0e12;
}

ul li a .active .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-250%);
  color: #ff0e12;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li a .icon .fa:last-child {
  color: #eeeeee;
}

ul li a:hover .icon .fa {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

  <ul>

    <div>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="index.html"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <li>
      <a class="button">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <li>
      <a>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <div>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <li>
      <a>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <div>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="settings.html"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <li>
      <a>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="active">
          <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>


  </ul>


</body>
```

Comment: No problem Hyperlys - glad I could help! =)